# How to Drag And Drop selected rows between DataGridViews

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, drag-and-drop

I need to implement drag and drop of the selected rows from one grid to the other:

my code:

datagridview1

```
Private Sub datagridview1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles datagridview1.MouseDown

    Dim info As DataGridView.HitTestInfo = Me.datagridview1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)

    If info.Type = DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell And e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then

        Me.datagridview1.DoDragDrop(datagridview1.SelectedRows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).OrderBy(Function(r) r.Index).ToArray, DragDropEffects.All)

    End If

End Sub
```

datagridview2

```
Private Sub datagridview2_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles datagridview2.DragEnter

    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All
End Sub

Private Sub datagridview2_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles datagridview2.DragDrop

    Try
        Dim Rows() As DataGridViewRow = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData(GetType(DataGridViewRow())), DataGridViewRow())

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In rows

            MsgBox(row.Cells("ID").Value)


        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

but there is an error in conversion.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a copy of the selected rows instead:

```
Dim dgrCopy(datagridview1.SelectedRows.Count - 1) As DataGridViewRow
datagridview1.SelectedRows.CopyTo(dgrCopy, 0)
Me.datagridview1.DoDragDrop(dgrCopy.OrderBy(Function(r) r.Index).ToArray, DragDropEffects.All)
```